# Invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

aws dynamodb query  --table-name shoutout-testing --key-condition-expression "Model = :a"

I tried this query but it's saying that :a is not defined

Comment: Define `:a` as a expression attribute value.

Comment: Cheers have you got a link to documentation on how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to also pass the `--expression-attribute-values` parameter to define this ":a". For example, `--expression-attribute-values '{ ":a": {"S": "hello"} }'`. Please check the CLI "query" documentation [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/dynamodb/query.html).